# How is "do" used with other verbs?

Tags: do-support

Which one is correct or are both correct? Please explain if there's any explanation.

> Let's kiss
>   Let's do kiss

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct, there is a difference in meaning.

*Do X* where X is the plain form of the verb is *required* for:

- questions - *Do/does/did X ... ?*
- negations - typically *do/does/did not X*
- in some idiomatic patterns where we don't want to repeat the main verb or are answering questions - *She went there, and I did too*, *Did she complete the task? Yeah, she did.*

and

- any other time, it's emphasis, and optional.

A reason for *do X* emphasis is to make it clear you want to do X as opposed to something else - and you were considering it earlier.

The usual situation (and implication created) is there was some indecisiveness or unclearness on what happened and then you made a decision on what to do.

Contrived example:

> So what happened?  Did you walk or run?
>
> Well, we wanted to walk, but it was better to run because of the dog.  So we did run (as opposed to walking).

Another contrived example of present tense usage:

> We need to go to work soon.
>
> I want some coffee.  Weren't you thinking of getting some earlier?
>
> Yeah, that's a good idea!  Let's do get coffee.

If there's any doubt, don't use the *do*.